# Java Array of InnerClass throwing java.lang.NoSuchFieldError

Tags: java, inner-classes

I am trying to brushup java after a long time. 
Any help is much appreciated.

For demonstration I have Animal Class that has an array of innerclass of Organs.

```
public class Animal 
   {
    String nameOfAnimal;
    Organs [] vitalOrgans = new Organs[3];

    public Animal()
    {
    }

    public String getNameOfAnimal() {
        return nameOfAnimal;
    }

    public void setNameOfAnimal(String nameOfAnimal) {
        this.nameOfAnimal = nameOfAnimal;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Animal{" + "nameOfAnimal=" + nameOfAnimal + "}";
    }
class Organs{

String nameOfOrgan; 
public String getNameOfOrgan() {
    return nameOfOrgan;
}
public void setNameOfOrgan(String nameOfOrgan) {
    this.nameOfOrgan = nameOfOrgan;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Organs{" + "nameOfOrgan=" + nameOfOrgan + '}';
}
```

}
}

Now in driver file when I make call there is no syntactical error but I get *"Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: vitalOrgans"*

```
    Animal mamal = new Animal(); 
    mamal.setNameOfAnimal("Chimp");
    mamal.vitalOrgans[0].setNameOfOrgan("Heart");
    System.out.println(mamal.vitalOrgans[0].getNameOfOrgan());
```

What would be the way to make this (or similar idea) to work. 
Thanks.

Comment: NoSuchFieldError != NullPointerException.

Comment: Your title describes a NullPointerException; your body describes a very different error...

Comment: (It would also help if you'd format your code more readably - use the post preview so that you can make sure it looks how you want it to look...)

Comment: Right! fixed the title error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to initialize the vitalOrgrans with new Organs(). Like:

```
public Animal() {
    for (int i = 0; i < vitalOrgans.length; i++) {
        vitalOrgans[i] = new Organs();
    }
}
```

Because when you say :

```
Organs[] vitalOrgans = new Organs[3];
```

You are creating an array of 3 null Organs. Hence the null pointer exception, when accessing "vitalOrgans[i].".

Comment: This doesn't solve the NoSuchField error, but it is going to solve the next error he will get once he fixes that.

Comment: Depends on where the driver is - if it is in the same package - "vitalOrgans" is visible (by default the variable has package scope). If outside then "vitalOrgans" needs to be made public, or better still would need a getter for "vitalOrgans".

Comment: Well, he did say he had a NoSuchField error in his original question, so it definitely wasn't, hence my original comment.

Answer (score 1):

Taking the relevant bit of code:

```
public class Animal 
{
    //...
    Organs [] vitalOrgans = new Organs[3];
    //...
}
```

Since your declaration of `vitalOrgans` was never given an access modifier (i.e. one of `private`, `public`, `protected`) it took on default access, which means only other classes in the same package can see it.  Since your other block of code is not in the same package, it cannot see the field.

A minimally viable modification to just make it work would be to set the access to `public`:

```
public class Animal 
{
    //...
    public Organs [] vitalOrgans = new Organs[3];
    //...
}
```

While this works, it's not necessarily the best solution, as if you ever change how vitalOrgans is represented, or need to perform any validation, those edits would have to be done throughout the application.  Thus, a better solution (and also, a major stylistic convention in Java for those exact reasons) is to make it (and all your fields, in fact) private and access via methods:

```
public class Animal {
    private String nameOfAnimal;
    private Organs[] vitalOrgans = new Organs[3];

    //...

    public Organs[] getVitalOrgans() {
        return vitalOrgans;
    }

    //Alternative accessor that fetches only one organ.
    public Organs getVitalOrgan(int index) {
        if(index >= 0 && index < vitalOrgans.length)
            return vitalOrgans[index];
        else
            return null;
    }

    public void setVitalOrgans(Organs[] vitalOrgans) {
        this.vitalOrgans = vitalOrgans
    }

    //...
}
```

Your caller could then access Organs via either form of the get method (note, you probably want Organs to be public):

```
Animal.Organs futureMammalHeart = mamal.getVitalOrgan(0); //Animal.Organs due to Organs being an inner class.
if(futureMammalHeart != null) //Demonstration of null check.  Safety first!
    futureMammalHeart.setNameOfOrgan("Heart");
Animal.Organs[] mammalianVitalOrgans = mamal.getVitalOrgans();
if(mammalianVitalOrgans != null) //Just in case...
    System.out.println(mamal.mammalianVitalOrgans[0].getNameOfOrgan());
```

Also, as Ari mentioned in his answer, don't forget to initialize the organs in your array, otherwise you will get a NullPointerException!

Comment: Thanks @Brandon for the details.